# lazyloading images - noscript fallback code

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I'm loading images on my site using js library `jquery lazyload2`, to display images I use the code below:

```
<img class="lazyload img-fluid" src="{{$product->getEncodedThumb()}}"  data-src="{{asset($product->getMainImage())}}" alt="{{$product->name}}">
```

Everything works fine so far, but I need to make the version of my site for users who don't have javascript enabled, how would I approach this? I could just replace all `src` tags on lazyloaded images with high quality images, but it would completely miss the point, as it would always download high quality images without lazyloading, how should I redesign my structure to allow for javascript lazyloading & noscript standard loading? Do I need to create completely different layout for noscript users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `img` tag is followed by `noscript` tag with embedded original image, i.e.

```css
/* hide lazyload images for disabled js */
.lazyload-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="lazyload lazyload-hidden img-fluid"
     src="{{$product->getEncodedThumb()}}"
     data-src="{{asset($product->getMainImage())}}"
     alt="{{$product->name}}">
<noscript>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{asset($product->getMainImage())}}" alt="{{$product->name}}">
</noscript>
```

```js
// show lazyload images
$('img[data-src]').removeClass('lazyload-hidden');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new built-in lazy loading in HTML

Just with adding loading="lazy" attribute to your 
like that:

```
<img src="https://test.photos/300.jpg" loading="lazy" />
```

Here you can see browser support:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr